# Compiling Metal framework for deployment target OSX 10.10

Tags: xcode, cocoa, metal

I have a project which is supported from OSX 10.10. Recently I had to work with Metal framework for image processing. Metal framework has only been introduced in 10.11. So my project won't compile as the deployment target is 10.10. How do I over come this? Can't I add #ifdef or something to compile the project and use the Metal features only on latest OS versions without changing the deployment target?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method to load the code associated with a dynamically loaded bundle, such as a plug-in or framework.

```
static NSBundle*        _MetalBundle    = nil;
static id<MTLDevice>    _MetalDevice    = nil;

static bool IsMetalSupported(int /*api*/)
{
    _MetalBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath: @"/System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework"];
    if (_MetalBundle)
    {
        [_MetalBundle load];
        _MetalDevice = ((MTLCreateSystemDefaultDeviceFunc)::dlsym(dlopen(0, RTLD_LOCAL | RTLD_LAZY), "MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice"))();
        if (_MetalDevice)
            return true;
    }

    [_MetalBundle unload];
    return false;
}
```

Comment: So I need to create a plugin with Metal related feature and load it dynamically based on the OS version. Is it?

Comment: This is one of the possible solutions.

Comment: Could you tell the other possible methods? Just curious to know them

Comment: I was able to create a bundle and load it in my application. But How do I create an instance of the principal class? It is of type `id` by default. I want to call a method and return the result. We usually import .h file to access instance methods right. But with bundles the files are not exposed.